# Intermitent dissapearence of mouse speed option

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

So, I just noticed that my computer (A desktop running 14.04 LTS) doesn't have the option to adjust the speed of my mouse, unless I plug in a certain mouse. (A really old one, to be specific.) However, settings that are saved when changed with this mouse plugged in are saved for other mice as well.

I noticed this when my wireless mouse died, and I plugged in my old corded backup that I've been using for at least ten years. It was way too slow, so per the norm, I went to the settings and adjusted the mouse speed up. Obviously, the slider was there, because I made the adjustment successfully.

Now, yesterday, I got new batteries for the wireless mouse and plugged it back in. The settings were set way to high for it, so I went to turn the sensitivity down. But alas, the slider for mouse speed was missing! Only the "Primary button" right/left and the "Double click speed" options were available.

I decided to go back to the last time I could use it; when the older mouse was plugged in. After unplugging my new mouse, and plugging in my older mouse, I went back into the settings. The slider for speed was back! I adjusted it to a painfully low setting, then saved and switched mice yet again. The speed was better, but still a little fast.

I was getting slightly impatient at this point. Luckily, it lead to a somewhat interesting, albeit expected, discovery. Plugging in both mice at once caused the slider to pop up (had the mouse settings open on my screen) and I could adjust it from there.

So, I guess what I wanted to ask was, why? Why does my computer do this? Could it be because the hardware on my machine is not new enough to properly detect the wireless mouse's hardware, despite Ubuntu's software? (Relatively old machine here.) Also, is there a fix other than plugging in this antique mouse?

Thanks for reading and helping!

Answer (score 1):

Just a workaround here - I am also affected by this bug, but the terminal command xset allows you to adjust the mouse speed using the command line.  I suggest doing a man xset to learn more about the command, but "xset m 1.3 0" is the magic number for me.  The format of the command is **xset m *speed* *threshold***.  More explanation on what threshold means can be found in the manpages.

The link to the bug in launchpad is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1132063).